# Automated screen-capturing on any browser, any website with no client-side plugin?

Tags: php, webkit, screen, capture

I am working on a webapp that allows users to input a URL of any websites, the webapp will then prepare a full screen-cap of the website, to be stored in server, or made available for download.

Ideally this should work on the server-side so there will not be a client-side dependency.

I found [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) but capturing a website that is encoded in Big5 would result in gibberish text. Websites that use Unicode works flawlessly tho.

Is there any other way to do this? PHP grabscreen works only in Windows, my target platform is Linux so that is not an option.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that too. My solution was to do like this guy did at his website: http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/

He using Javascript canvas...

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

phantomjs (headless webkit) should do the trick.
http://phantomjs.org/

also check out this page (under Screenshot Utilities)
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Related-Projects